# Breaking the line inside a PHP script (echoing images)

Tags: html, css

Trying to add an awards system on a public profile page. The awards are echoed from mySQL as images. The thing is, a maximum of 5 awards can be shown, and in the next line there is no space between it and the first line. How can I add it, possibly with `<br>`, but if something else is better, it's also welcome!

[image: Screenshot of how it looks right now]

I tried some `<<<EOD` , but it got too complicated and it didn't work. Tried the naive approach, adding `<br>` after the echo, but obviously it didn't work either. Tried increasing the padding, it also didn't work at all.

```
 <div class="row">
    <?php if(is_array($allawards)) { ?>
        <p style="padding: 10px">
            <?php /* To show the image: */ ?>
             <?php foreach($allawards as $award) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $award->image; ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $award->descrip; ?>">&nbsp;
             } ?>
         </p>
         <?php } ?>
         <br/>
     </div>
```

Comment: Like everything related to aesthetic: with CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not PHP task, you need to use simple CSS.

Margin-bottom?

`img {margin-bottom: 5px;}`

Margin-top to 6th and others?

`img:nth-child(5) ~ img {margin-top: 5px;}`

Comment: This is correct OP just needs to margin-bottom or padding-bottom or paddling-the-bottom

Comment: @Daryll: it depends... When the white box has padding-bottom 20px, the gap will be bigger adding margin/padding-bottom. Better one solution is to use `margin-top` for 2nd and other rows.

Comment: @Daryll: compare divs in example https://jsfiddle.net/La8qx2ny/... The first one has bottom indent 40px (20px itself + 20px from images), the second one 20px, which is correctly...

Comment: True although it is possible they could use margin-bottom if they did `:not(:last-child) {margin-bottom: 20px;}` as in https://jsfiddle.net/m4wd1pxg/ Regardless there are many ways the OP could do this with CSS.

Comment: @Daryll: not at all... If there will be 3 images in row, you can't use just `:not(:last-child)`, because there are 3 'last children'. The last row can be uncomplete (eg. just 2 images), responsive (sometimes 3 images in the last rows, sometimes 2, sometimes 1)... I use example with 1 image in row, the OP asked for 5 images in row. Your solution isn't good, at least there are better ones.

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach you can increment a counter; after you echo, you can check if the counter is at five, and break if so.

```
$counter = 1;
foreach
  ...
  echo ...
  if ($counter == 5) echo '<br>';
  $counter++;
```

---

Or, instead of fixing this with a manual break, you may look to your styling to solve this a little more simply and more dynamically. With [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) you can specify the area to have 5 elements wide, and a row-gap of however much space you want between each set of 5 awards, like so:

```css
#awards_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; //1fr each instead of autos so they're always 
  the same width
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
}
```